# Best way to update CF app, db and server code

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I've built a Compact Framework application to be used by delivery drivers. The system includes a WCF Service and SQL database on the server as well as a SQL CE database and CF application running on the mobile device.

Now the question is how to I update all this easily when I release new versions? The problems are:

- it may be deployed to hundreds of PDAs
- when first installed on a PDA the SQL CE database has to be populated. This can take a while. I don't want to have to do this each time the app is upgraded so I'm going to have to run scripts to update the db schema rather than just replacing the whole file and repopulating it.
- the WCF service code will need to be updated
- the SQL database schema will need to be updated

I can see solutions to all this but it seems like a lot of work. I thought it may be helpful to get a few tips before I launch into it all.

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using WmAutoUpdate. Please refer to [Automatically updating Compact Framework application code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457699/automatically-updating-compact-framework-application-code)

Answer (score 1):

I think , you should divide your whole deployment in two phases

1- Client Deployment where you can upgrade your client ( PDAs + SQL CE )

2- Serevr Deployment where you can upgrade your Server side functionality ( WCF Service code + SQL Server database)

so these two phase must be independent of each other i.e. you can deploy both the phase simulteneously.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Saurabh. I didn't mark it as the answer but it's certainly a valid point.

Comment: Well no-one else has added any further comments so I've marked this as an answer. Thanks again for the suggestion.