# Automatically updating Compact Framework application code

Tags: c#, deployment, compact-framework, clickonce, auto-update

I've built a Compact Framework application to be used by delivery drivers. This runs on a SQL CE database and connects to a WCF service on a web server. I need a way to update the system when I release new versions.

I'm hoping that I can install a new version of the WCF code in a new folder on the web server and then somehow trigger the mobile devices to update the local CF application and also connect to the new WCF service URL. So far I've found 2 frameworks:

WmAutoUpdate
http://github.com/seboslaw/wmautoupdate

AppToDate 
http://www.modaco.com/category/332/apptodate/

And some old sample code from Microsoft:

.NET Compact Framework Sample: Auto Updater
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=8FC47C2C-FC61-4D82-ABAE-F34DC1BFCD3F&displaylang=en

Before I spend hours investigating these options I'm hoping for some tips from others who have gone before. What are the pros and cons of the different frameworks and techniques? I've read various other posts on this topic but they haven't including reviews of these frameworks.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are good places to start.

If you're using a tighlty locked down device and restricting internet access (as I suspect you are) then AppToDate may not be appropriate. Depending on how you're locking down the devices you may have to write something yourself. WmAutoUpdate should serve as a good starting point for this.

Talk to the manufacturers of the devices your using also, as many have their own software solutions to just this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and sorry about the late reply. I ended up using WmAutoUpdate and so far it's working very nicely :)